# Missing button "Query window" in XAMPP phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

with my new XAMPP (v5.6.11) install on my Win 10 machine, I am missing the button in the navigation panel that opens the query window in phpMyAdmin (v 4.4.12)
Anyone knows how to get it back?

[image]

Cheers
Greg

ps. This button is missing [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been replaced by the Console (at the bottom of main panel) and by the "Edit inline" feature to edit queries.

Comment: Is the extra query-window/pop-up now entirely gone? I don't like the console and would prefer the popup. Is there a way to enable it? The option $cfg['EditInWindow'] seems to be gone.

Comment: Yes it's entirely gone, but see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11983